# Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value E/flutter (28057): #0 DBHelper._createDB

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite, dart-null-safety

I created a class for database operations, when i trigger the function of insert to data base to print occurs with this error: ***Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value E/flutter (28057): #0      DBHelper._createDB***, also there is no print occures once initialize an object of `DBHelper`. i think null-able _db object is the reason. what is the solution?

**database class:**

```
class DBHelper {
  DBHelper._();
  factory DBHelper() => instance;
  static final DBHelper instance = DBHelper._();
  Database? _db;

  Future<Database> _createDB() async {
    // If the app is opened just now
    if (_db == null) return _db!;
    // Open db too create a db
    // or to take an instance of it

    // Get the default databases location.
    // and join the name of app db
    String path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'todo.db');
    return _db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database database, int version) {

      database.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE tasks(id integer autoincrement PRIMARY KEY,content varchar(150),status varchar(9),isFinished BOOLEAN) ");
      print("\n TABLE executed \n");
    }, onOpen: (_) {
      print("\n opened \n ");
    });
  }

  Future<int> insertNoteToDB(NoteDatabaseModel noteDatabaseModel) async {
    Database _database = await _createDB();
    return await _database.rawInsert(
        'INSERT INTO tasks(content,status) values("${noteDatabaseModel.content}", "today")');
    // return await _database!.insert('tasks', noteDatabaseModel.toJason());
  }
}
```

**the implementation of sql:**

```
class TodayPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TodayPage();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      DBHelper dbHelper=DBHelper();

     return  MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: () async{
                        // DBHelper _db = DBHelper.instance;
                      
                        NoteDatabaseModel note=NoteDatabaseModel(content: "hey",status: "today");
                         int x= await dbHelper.
                         insertNodeToDB(note);
                       print("\n print all Data ${  await dbHelper.
                         insertNodeToDB(note)}\n");
                      },
                      child: const Text("Click Me"),
                      ),
                    ),
          ],
    ); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think this line does:

```
if (_db == null) return _db!;
```

If I would have to guess, I'd say it should be:

```
if (_db != null) return _db;
```